# Unable To Use GetMerchandisedProducts from eBay API According To Authentication Issue

Tags: python, python-requests, ebay-api

I published this post: https://forums.developer.ebay.com/questions/31327/unable-to-use-getmerchandisedproducts-according-to.html, but nobody answered me. Therefore I copy the same question over here, any help will be highly appreciated:

I believe the problem is something related to token issues. If I understood correctly, there are several types of tokens - and I am completely confused, here is my code:

```
from requests import get 

category_id = "11071" # TVs
url =  f"https://api.ebay.com/buy/marketing/v1_beta/merchandised_product?metric_name=BEST_SELLING&category_id={category_id}&limit=100"
postman_headers = {
     "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
     "Authorization" : "Bearer " + token 
} 

response = get(url, headers = postman_headers)
print(response.content)
```

However, it returns me:

```
b'{"errors":[{"errorId":1100,"domain":"ACCESS","category":"REQUEST","message":"Access  denied","longMessage":"Insufficient permissions to fulfill the request."}]}'
```

Can someone point me what I am supposed to do? Clear instructions will be very helpful. I had also tried to go to "The client credentials grant flow", but eventually it resulted in a dead end.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: what's the point of using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` with `GET`?

Comment: You are right, it's redundant, but it doesn't help in any way